# Deploy Angular4 (Angular) created using angular-cli to Google App Engine

Tags: maven, google-app-engine, visual-studio-code, angular

I have created a Angular4 or simply "Angular" application using Angular-CLI. Now i could run it locally using "ng serve" and it works fine. Now i want to deploy it to Google App Engine, ng build --prod builds all files to dist folder.

Now how should i deploy them to google app engine?

EDIT:

I forgot to mention this, i want to deploy using maven. is there any dependency i can add to pom.xml. so that i can do everything from mvn?

Comment: You have to create an app.yaml for your frontend code.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Deploying basic Angular 2 app to Google App Engine](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/39782506/deploying-basic-angular-2-app-to-google-app-engine)

Answer (score 2):

you can use maven in this way as a wrapper to create the build and to create a zip to upload. This is an implementation using yarn 
and npm.

${project.artifactId}

```
<plugins>

  <!-- ############################## -->
  <!-- npm scripts                    -->
  <!-- ############################## -->

  <plugin>
    <groupId>org.codehaus.mojo</groupId>
    <artifactId>exec-maven-plugin</artifactId>
    <executions>
      <execution>
        <id>exec-yarn-install</id>
        <phase>generate-sources</phase>
        <configuration>
          <executable>npm</executable>
          <arguments>
            <argument>install</argument>
            <argument>--global</argument>
            <argument>yarn</argument>
          </arguments>
        </configuration>
        <goals>
          <goal>exec</goal>
        </goals>
      </execution>
      <execution>
        <id>exec-project-dependencies-install</id>
        <phase>generate-sources</phase>
        <configuration>
          <executable>yarn</executable>
        </configuration>
        <goals>
          <goal>exec</goal>
        </goals>
      </execution>

      <!-- run `ng build -prod -aot` -->
      <!-- * clean dist/ before generating distribution files -->
      <execution>
        <id>exec-compile</id>
        <phase>generate-sources</phase>
        <configuration>
          <executable>yarn</executable>
          <arguments>
            <argument>run</argument>
            <argument>build</argument>
          </arguments>
        </configuration>
        <goals>
          <goal>exec</goal>
        </goals>
      </execution>
    </executions>
  </plugin>

  <!-- generate zip -->
  <plugin>
    <groupId>org.apache.maven.plugins</groupId>
    <artifactId>maven-assembly-plugin</artifactId>
    <version>2.3</version>
    <configuration>
      <descriptors>
        <descriptor>src/assembly/static.xml</descriptor>
      </descriptors>
    </configuration>
    <executions>
      <execution>
        <id>make-assembly</id>
        <phase>package</phase>
        <goals>
          <goal>single</goal>
        </goals>
      </execution>
    </executions>
  </plugin>
</plugins>
```

Answer (score 0):

I created a App Engine yaml for serving Angular 4 dist folder. Looking for any feedback on how to improve it.

```
service: stage
runtime: python27
api_version: 1
threadsafe: true

skip_files:
- ^(?!dist)  # Skip any files not in the dist folder

handlers:
# Routing for bundles to serve directly
- url: /((?:inline|main|polyfills|styles|vendor)\.[a-z0-9]+\.bundle\.js)
  secure: always
  redirect_http_response_code: 301
  static_files: dist/\1
  upload: dist/.*

# Routing for a prod styles.bundle.css to serve directly
- url: /(styles\.[a-z0-9]+\.bundle\.css)
  secure: always
  redirect_http_response_code: 301
  static_files: dist/\1
  upload: dist/.*

# Routing for typedoc, assets and favicon.ico to serve directly
- url: /((?:assets|docs)/.*|favicon\.ico)
  secure: always
  redirect_http_response_code: 301
  static_files: dist/\1
  upload: dist/.*

# Any other requests are routed to index.html for angular to handle so we don't need hash URLs
- url: /.*
  secure: always
  redirect_http_response_code: 301
  static_files: dist/index.html
  upload: dist/index\.html
  http_headers:
    Strict-Transport-Security: max-age=31536000; includeSubDomains
    X-Frame-Options: DENY
```