# Deploying app with python backend and Angular frontend on GAE

Tags: python, angular, google-app-engine

For a college project, I'm developing a RESTful API. The API has been coded in python and deployed with the Google App Engine (which works fine).

I've developped an Angular (5) application as the frontend which makes HTTP requests to that API.

The question is - how do I deploy both backend and frontend on the same Google App Engine project? Am I supposed to merge both directories (python and Angular apps) and deploy the whole thing directly?

Comment: i'm facing a similar project , did you find any documentation for this?

Comment: you're supposed to build the angular project with `ng build`, copy the created files from angular's `dist/app` folder into the python app's `dist/` folder for ex and edit the appengine app's yaml file to read and start with those files - i'll come back wit an answer if i'll find out how

Comment: check here https://stackoverflow.com/questions/39782506/deploying-basic-angular-2-app-to-google-app-engine