# Accessing GAE deployed Angular app

Tags: angular, google-app-engine

I recently was successful in my attempts in deploying my angular app code using bitbucket pipeline to GAE flex environment. Though the push was successful when I tried to access it from GAE, it throws me a 404 error like this

**Error: Not Found
The requested URL / was not found on this server.**

This is my app.yaml file

```
runtime: python27
api_version: 1
threadsafe: true



handlers:
# Routing for bundles to serve directly
- url: /((?:inline|main|polyfills|styles|vendor)\.[a-z0-9]+\.bundle\.js)
  secure: always
  redirect_http_response_code: 301
  static_files: dist/\1
  upload: dist/.*

  # Routing for a prod styles.bundle.css to serve directly
  - url: /(styles\.[a-z0-9]+\.bundle\.css)
    secure: always
    redirect_http_response_code: 301
    static_files: dist/\1
    upload: dist/.*

    # Routing for typedoc, assets and favicon.ico to serve directly
    - url: /((?:assets|docs)/.*|favicon\.ico)
     secure: always
     redirect_http_response_code: 301
     static_files: dist/\1
     upload: dist/.*


     # Any other requests are routed to index.html for angular to 
     handle so we don't need hash URLs
     - url: /.*
       secure: always
       redirect_http_response_code: 301
       static_files: dist/index.html
       upload: dist/index\.html
```

This is my bitbucket pipeline

```
 image: node:9.11.1
  pipelines:

  custom:

   default:

     - step:

       script: 

         -  npm install -g @angular/cli@latest

         - ng build --prod
         - cp app.yaml dist
         - ls dist
         - cd dist

         - curl -o /tmp/google-cloud-sdk.tar.gz https://dl.google.com/dl/cloudsdk/channels/rapid/downloads/google-cloud-sdk-190.0.0-linux-x86_64.tar.gz

         - tar -xvf /tmp/google-cloud-sdk.tar.gz -C /tmp/

         - /tmp/google-cloud-sdk/install.sh -q

         - source /tmp/google-cloud-sdk/path.bash.inc
         - echo $GCLOUD_API_KEYFILE | base64 --decode --ignore-garbage > ./gcloud-api-key.json
         - gcloud config set project $GCLOUD_PROJECT

         - gcloud components install app-engine-java

         - gcloud auth activate-service-account --key-file gcloud-api-key.json

         - echo $GCLOUD_API_KEYFILE > /tmp/client-secret.json  

         - gcloud config set project $GCLOUD_PROJECT
         - gcloud app update --split-health-checks --project adtecy-ui 

         - gcloud app deploy app.yaml
```

This is what GAE logs show and I cannot find anything meaningful from it

```
168.94.245.21 - - [15/May/2018:13:15:13 +0530] "GET / HTTP/1.1" 404 - - 
"Mozilla/5.0 (Macintosh; Intel Mac OS X 10_13_4) AppleWebKit/537.36 
(KHTML, like Gecko) Chrome/66.0.3359.139 Safari/537.36" "adtecy- 
ui.appspot.com" ms=NaN cpu_ms=0 cpm_usd=0 loading_request=0 instance=- 
app_engine_release=1.9.54 trace_id=85d126d7cbeea49449c4c095011e00eb
Expand all | Collapse all {
httpRequest: {…}  
insertId:  "5afa900a00001b8c0b7302c3"  
labels: {…}  
logName:  "projects/adtecy- 
 ui/logs/appengine.googleapis.com%2Frequest_log"  
operation: {…}  
protoPayload: {…}  
receiveTimestamp:  "2018-05-15T07:45:14.007655496Z"  
resource: {…}  
severity:  "WARNING"  
timestamp:  "2018-05-15T07:45:13.999645Z"  
trace:  "85d126d7cbeea49449c4c095011e00eb"  
}
```

Could you guys help me out?

Comment: First thing: why are you using Python runtime (at the top of your `app.yaml` file) for an Angular app? The second thing is that you have wrong indentation in your `app.yaml` which was corrected in Venkata's answer.

Comment: @AniaRudzińska I corrected the indentation problem that I had. But I was unsure of what runtime to use and hence went with python. Can you suggest me what runtime to use? I have also changed the image docker in pipeline from nodejs to python (installed the npm from debian ) but that failed as well :(

Comment: @AniaRudzińska Do you think that my handlers section of app.yaml also has issues. I navigate to the dist folder and then try to push the code using `gcloud app deploy ` so I find that using dist in the handlers section is of no use. Also I removed the `/` in the handlers - static_files and upload attributes and still no success. Can you provide suggestions?

Answer (score 2):

Few things changed with the latest version of Angular CLI. If you are using CLI version > 6 use the following yaml, this yaml makes sure the handlers for js and css files are correct (removing the .bundle and adds runtime)

```
runtime: python27
api_version: 1
threadsafe: true

skip_files:
- ^(?!dist)  # Skip any files not in the dist folder

handlers:
# Routing for bundles to serve directly
- url: /((?:inline|main|polyfills|styles|runtime|vendor)\.[a-z0-9]+\.js)
  secure: always
  redirect_http_response_code: 301
  static_files: dist/\1
  upload: dist/.*

# Routing for a prod styles.bundle.css to serve directly
- url: /(styles\.[a-z0-9]+\.css)
  secure: always
  redirect_http_response_code: 301
  static_files: dist/\1
  upload: dist/.*

# Routing for typedoc, assets and favicon.ico to serve directly
- url: /((?:assets|docs)/.*|favicon\.ico)
  secure: always
  redirect_http_response_code: 301
  static_files: dist/\1
  upload: dist/.*

# Any other requests are routed to index.html for angular to handle so we don't need hash URLs
- url: /.*
  secure: always
  redirect_http_response_code: 301
  static_files: dist/index.html
  upload: dist/index\.html
  http_headers:
    Strict-Transport-Security: max-age=31536000; includeSubDomains
    X-Frame-Options: DENY
```

On top this, you should also edit your angular.json (which used to be angular-cli.json) and set "outputpath" to just "dist" rather than "dist/your-app-name" for gcloud app deploy to pick things up correctly.

Comment: by "outputPath" you mean the "outDir" in angular.json/angular-cli.json , correct?

Comment: I tried deploying but it is giving me the same error :(

Comment: Do you see issues with handlers. It seems with whatever method I try I cannot get it working :(